# Transform headers to cells and join

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Current data:

[image: Current data]

Desired outcome:

[image: desired outcome]

I considering writing a basic VBA script, to loop through and concatenate. However since this will be running through 44 columns 25k-130k rows. I would prefer a more efficient solution.

I believe this could perhaps be accomplished fairly efficiently with power query. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power Query is good here. Unpivot the non-Item columns and then aggregate with `Text.Combine`.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    UnpivotColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Item"}, "Qualities", "Value"),
    GroupRows = Table.Group(UnpivotColumns, {"Item"}, {{"Qualities", each Text.Combine([Qualities], ","), type text}})
in
    GroupRows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim vResult() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim r As Long, n As Integer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1) 'data Sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2) 'result Sheet
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    
    ReDim vResult(1 To r, 1 To 2)
    
    For i = 2 To r
        n = 0
        For j = 2 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            If vDB(i, j) = "Yes" Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                vR(n) = vDB(1, j)
            End If
        Next j
        vResult(i, 1) = vDB(i, 1)
        If n Then
            vResult(i, 2) = Join(vR, ",")
        End If
    Next i
    vResult(1, 1) = "Item"
    vResult(1, 2) = "Qualities"
        
    With toWs
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(r, 2) = vResult
    End With
End Sub
```

### Sheet1 image

[image]

### Sheet2 image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**UDF Option**

This is an interesting question.  Even though you already have 2 solid answers, I thought I would look at a third option as a coding exercise. To make the `ConcatSpecial()` UDF work, copy the code below to a standard module in your workbook.  Then, in sheet 2, enter `=ConcatSpecial(…` in the cell next to `apples` and underneath `Qualities`.  Between the parenthesis, highlight the range on sheet 1 on the `apples` row from columns A – D (whatever those columns may be).

All you need to do then is copy the formula down the full range on sheet 2 wherever you have values in the `Item` column.  **You must ensure that the order of the items in sheet 2 is the same as on sheet 1 for this to work.**  I would recommend copying the values from sheets 1 to 2 to ensure this is the case.

Please try it and let me know how you go.

```
Public Function ConcatSpecial(MyArea As Range) As String
Dim c As Range, MyString As String, myheader As String
    For Each c In MyArea
        myheader = Sheet1.Cells(1, c.Column)
        MyString = IIf(c = "", MyString & "", MyString & myheader & ",")
        Next
    ConcatSpecial = Left(MyString, Len(MyString) - 1)
End Function
```